# OS Used to Write WSS Extentions

Tags: sharepoint

I'm very new to Microsoft Windows SharePoint software, let alone .NET altogether, and I want to know if it is possible to develop extentions using Windows XP to write extentions for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 (WSS).

I would also like to ask if it is possible to deploy extentions without having "Full Control" access to the WSS solution -- I have the permissions of a "Designer". If so, where exactly are the extentions deployed to?

I would highly appreciate it if you could recommend a book or two as well.

Thanks, people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it depends on your definition of "extensions".  Anything that requires developing .Net assemblies will require a much higher set of permissions.  Higher than Full Control.  You'll need to work with the SharePoint Farm administrators to deploy SharePoint Solutions.

On the plus side, you can code using Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 on WinXP to develop these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint development typically requires that you develop on a server running SharePoint. The SharePoint Server Object Model only runs locally.

This changes with SharePoint 2010 only in that you can install SharePoint 2010 on a Vista or Windows 7 machine.

You can develop on Windows XP if you don't mind not being able to debug, and if you don't mind not being able to deploy using Visual Studio.

Comment: Wow. Very informative. Would it make more sense to just Remote Access into the server that's running WSS and perform any development work there?

Comment: @playwiz: yes, people typically use Remote Access, or else run the server in a Virtual Machine. Keep in mind, some of the development may be disruptive, so you may not want to develop on your production WSS box.

Comment: @John Saunders: If not, then how else would I be able to debug my work?

Comment: @play: debug it on your development server, then deploy it to production. This is just the way any other software is developed.

Comment: @John: Hmm. This implies that I must have WSS installed on my development server then, because I don't see any other way of debug without the actual production version being on my local drive for testing. Is that correct? And if that's the case, I must find a way to copy the production WSS unto a new development server to begin extension development?

Comment: @playwiz: this is the way it was up to SharePoint 2010. Keep in mind, you don't have to "copy" the production server.

Comment: @John: If I don't have to "copy" the production server, how should I go about extending a Web Part (actually trying to extend a field property on a web part) that pertains to the solution on the production server?

Comment: @play: you develop the solution, place it into source control, then deploy to production. When you have a change, you change the source control version, test in the development environment, then check back in to source control and deploy to production. Just like "real" development.

Comment: @John: I really appreciated all the help and information, Sir Saunders.  Thank you. :]